# How to resolve SQLAlchemy Union Throwing Error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, union

I'm using SQL Alchemy(Python, SQLServer) Union on two queries. It throws me the below error. Please help me in resolving it.

```
query1 = db.query(Employee.LastName).filter(Employee.Age == 30).all()
query2 = db.query(Employee.LastName).filter(Employee.Salary > 25000).all()
query3 = union(query1, query2).all()
```

```
**"SELECT construct for inclusion in UNION or other set construct expected, got [('Joseph',),('Alan',),('Joseph',)]."**
```

Also tried the below query and it throws the below error

```
query1 = db.query(Employee.LastName).filter(Employee.Age == 30).all()
query2 = db.query(Employee.LastName).filter(Employee.Salary > 25000).all()
query3 = query1.union(query2).all()
```

```
**"'list' object has no attribute 'union'"**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `.all()` from the first two queries, it turns the queries into lists, but you want to pass `Query` instances to `union`.

```py
query1 = db.query(Employee.LastName).filter(Employee.Age == 30) # <- Query
query2 = db.query(Employee.LastName).filter(Employee.Salary > 25000) # <- Query
result = query1.union(query2).all() # <- List
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I made a slight modification to third line and then it started working.   
                              result = query1.union(query2).all()